# Prevent double-escaped JSON in FOR JSON output in SQL

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a small problem in my case **because in my case a column can contain text 'John' directly or text as array '["John","Smith"]' both. So how can I prevent double-escaped JSON in FOR JSON output**? I think I am doing something wrong here. Please check my example:

```
Create table #jsonTest(NameList varchar(max))
insert into #jsonTest(NameList)
select '["John","Smith"]'
```

Now if I want its output it will give correct output from this (without escape character):

```
select JSON_QUERY(NameList) NameList from #jsonTest for json auto
```

Output:

```
[{"NameList":["John","Smith"]}]
```

Simple text example:

```
truncate table #jsonTest
insert into #jsonTest(NameList)
Select 'John'
```

Now for this **I have to change my select query for the correct output because JSON_QUERY, as mentioned, it only returns objects and arrays.** So i've changed it to this:

```
select case when ISJSON(NameList) = 1 then JSON_QUERY(NameList) else NameList end NameList from #jsonTest for json auto
```

Output:

```
[{"NameList":"John"}]
```

Now **It will give correct output for now but if I insert previous data again and try upper select query**

```
truncate table #jsonTest
insert into #jsonTest(NameList)
select '["John","Smith"]'

select case when ISJSON(NameList) = 1 then JSON_QUERY(NameList) else NameList end NameList from #jsonTest for json auto
```

Output:

```
[{"NameList":"[\"John\",\"Smith\"]"}]
```

then **it is giving escape characters in output**. What is wrong in the code?

Comment: "column can contain array or text". No, there are no arrays in SQL Server. Everything you get is text, therefore it is qualified appropriately. Please read http://xyproblem.info/ and then ask your real question.

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz I've edited my mistake there. What i meant column can contain text 'John' directly or text as array '["John","Smith"]' both So how can I prevent double-escaped JSON in FOR JSON output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/how-for-json-escapes-special-characters-and-control-characters-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#escaping-of-special-characters) - *If the source data contains special characters, the FOR JSON clause escapes them in the JSON output with '\'*. Of course, as you already know, when [JSON_QUERY() is used with FOR JSON AUTO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#using-json_query-with-for-json), *FOR JSON doesn't escape special characters in the JSON_QUERY return value*.

Your problem is the fact, that your data is not always a JSON. So, one possible approach is to generate a statement with duplicate column names (`NameList`). By default `FOR JSON AUTO` does not include `NULL` values in the output, so the result is the expected JSON. Just note, that you must not use `INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES` in the statement or the final JSON will contain duplicate keys.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE #jsonTest(NameList varchar(max))
insert into #jsonTest(NameList)
select '["John","Smith"]'
insert into #jsonTest(NameList)
Select 'John'
```

Statement:

```
SELECT
   JSON_QUERY(CASE WHEN ISJSON(NameList) = 1 THEN JSON_QUERY(NameList) END) AS NameList,
   CASE WHEN ISJSON(NameList) = 0 THEN NameList END AS NameList
FROM #jsonTest 
FOR JSON AUTO
```

Result:

```
[{"NameList":["John","Smith"]},{"NameList":"John"}]
```

Comment: Thank you so much mate! Can you please help in this also [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60376495/how-to-update-data-as-json-array-and-select-data-as-json-array-in-sql-server)